# R Diverging bar char ggplot2: How to change the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, scale

I would like to create such a "diverging bar chart" (https://r-charts.com/part-whole/diverging-bar-chart-ggplot2/);

** My problem is that I would like to adjust the scale of the graph and the diverging bar plots to the actual scale of the question. A five-point Likert scale was used: 1 - significantly increased, 2 - increased, 3 - unchanged, 4 - decreased and 5 - significantly decreased.**

The center of the X-axis is therefore 3 (unchanged); values below 3 should go to the left (significant increase); the smaller the value, the longer the "bar plot". Values above 3 should be plotted to the right; the higher the value, the longer the bar plot.

My current code looks like this; the plot is not what i want, because the scale does not reflect the "true scale".

With "mean_data_transformed "I wanted to try to adapt the values to the scale somehow; but that didn't work. Presumably this does not need to be done....

```
str <- df %>%
  dplyr::select(starts_with("f_22")) %>%
  na.omit()

variable_names <- c(
  "f_22a" = "M",
  "f_22b" = "S",
  "f_22c" = "H",
  "f_22d" = "V",
  "f_22e" = "F",
  "f_22f" = "J",
  "f_22g" = "R",
  "f_22h" = "F",
  "f_22i" = "M",
  "f_22j" = "p",
  "f_22k" = "a",
  "f_22l" = "Z"
)
mean_data <- str %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("f_22"), ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "variable", values_to = "mean_value") %>%
  mutate(label = factor(variable_names[variable], levels = variable_names[order(mean_value)]))

mean_data_transformed <- mean_data %>%
  mutate(mean_value = ifelse(mean_value < 3, -mean_value, mean_value))

head(mean_data_transformed)

variable mean_value label                
  <chr>         <dbl> <fct>                
1 f_22a         -1.78 M              
2 f_22b          3.28 S           
3 f_22c         -2.67 H          
4 f_22d         -2.67 V         
5 f_22e          3.13 F
6 f_22f         -2.64 J        
> 

color <- ifelse(mean_data_transformed$mean_value < 0, "pink", "lightblue")


ggplot(mean_data_transformed, aes(y = reorder(label, mean_value), x = mean_value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           show.legend = FALSE,
           fill = color) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(-3, 3, by = 1),
                     limits = c(min(mean_data_transformed$mean_value) - 0.5,max(mean_data_transformed$mean_value) + 0.5), labels = c("Zunahme","","","Unverändert","","","Abnahme"))+
  xlab("") +
  ylab("")
```

EDIT::

> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] extrafont_0.19     ggthemes_4.2.4     wesanderson_0.3.6  psych_2.3.3        gtsummary_1.7.1    data.table_1.14.8  RColorBrewer_1.1-3 ggpubr_0.6.0
[9] lubridate_1.9.2    forcats_1.0.0      stringr_1.5.0      purrr_1.0.1        readr_2.1.4        tibble_3.2.1       ggplot2_3.4.2      tidyverse_2.0.0
[17] tidyr_1.3.0        dplyr_1.1.2        haven_2.5.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tidyselect_1.2.0     xfun_0.39            lattice_0.20-45      carData_3.0-5        colorspace_2.1-0     vctrs_0.6.1          generics_0.1.3
[8] htmltools_0.5.5      utf8_1.2.3           rlang_1.1.0          pillar_1.9.0         glue_1.6.2           withr_2.5.2          lifecycle_1.0.4
[15] munsell_0.5.0        ggsignif_0.6.4       gtable_0.3.3         labeling_0.4.2       knitr_1.42           tzdb_0.3.0           fastmap_1.1.1
[22] parallel_4.1.3       fansi_1.0.4          Rttf2pt1_1.3.12      broom_1.0.4          Rcpp_1.0.10          scales_1.2.1         backports_1.4.1
[29] abind_1.4-5          farver_2.1.1         mnormt_2.1.1         hms_1.1.3            digest_0.6.31        stringi_1.7.12       rstatix_0.7.2
[36] grid_4.1.3           cli_3.6.1            tools_4.1.3          magrittr_2.0.3       extrafontdb_1.0      car_3.1-2            pkgconfig_2.0.3
[43] broom.helpers_1.13.0 osmdata_0.2.5        xml2_1.3.3           timechange_0.2.0     gt_0.9.0             rstudioapi_0.14      R6_2.5.1
[50] nlme_3.1-155         compiler_4.1.3

DATAFRAME for the ggplot:

"mean_data"

variable mean_value label
f_22a    1.782787   M
f_22b    3.284836   S
f_22c    2.665984   H
f_22d    2.670082   v
f_22e    3.126025   F
f_22f    2.639344   J
f_22g    2.657787   R
f_22h    2.172131   F
f_22i    2.485656   M
f_22j    3.630123   P
f_22k    2.775615   A
f_22l    3.363730   Z

EDIT 2 (16/01/2024) I WANT THIS PLOT AS A BARPLOT (Not a stacked bar plot - just the lolipop-plot as a barplot; same color)

```
 mean_data_test <- str %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("f_22"), ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "variable", values_to = "mean_value") %>%
  mutate(label = factor(variable_names[variable], levels = variable_names[order(mean_value)]))



variable_names <- c(
  "f_22a" = "wetgqwfsa",
  "f_22b" = "sdgsvyx",
  "f_22c" = "sdfg",
  "f_22d" = "adhf",
  "f_22e" = "yxc",
  "f_22f" = "asfd",
  "f_22g" = "ag",
  "f_22h" = "wetggasg",
  "f_22i" = "zöotukt",
  "f_22j" = "qwerqwr",
  "f_22k" = "ybcv",
  "f_22l" = "afdaf"
)




# Alternative plot with better value display
ggplot(mean_data_test, aes(x = label, y = mean_value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = label, xend = label, y = 3, yend = mean_value), color = "grey", size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(mean_value < 3,"pink", "lightblue")), size = 7) +
  annotate("text", x = mean_data_test$label, y = mean_data_test$mean_value, label = round(mean_data_test$mean_value, 1), color = "black", size = 3, vjust = 0.5) +  # Add mean as text
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = "dashed", color = "black", size = 1) +
  scale_color_identity() +  
  scale_y_reverse(limits = c(5, 1), breaks = 1:5, labels = c("Zunahme", "", "Unverändert", "", "Abnahme")) + 
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), 
    text = element_text(size = 14, family = "sans")
  ) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Value of Y") +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.9) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: See e.g. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77615299/plotting-likert-type-questions-with-some-non-respondents/77615716#77615716](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77615299/plotting-likert-type-questions-with-some-non-respondents/77615716#77615716) for two approaches to create a Likert chart. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data shared using `dput()`.

Comment: I tried to give some more information; sorry the dataset is not formatted like it should be ...does it help? The link to your e.g did not help, because I don't understand..sorry

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer by @AllanCameron on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77615643/12993861) should give you the desired result.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(
  id = seq(n),
  f_22a = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE, n),
  f_22b = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE, n),
  f_22c = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE, n),
  f_22d = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE, n),
  f_22e = sample(1:5, replace = TRUE, n)
)

answers <- c(
  "significantly increased", "increased", "unchanged",
  "decreased", "significantly decreased"
)

variable_names <- c(
  "f_22a" = "M",
  "f_22b" = "S",
  "f_22c" = "H",
  "f_22d" = "V",
  "f_22e" = "F"
)

df %>%
  dplyr::select(starts_with("f_22")) |>
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Q", values_to = "ans") |>
  count(Q, ans) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  mutate(percent = n / sum(n), .by = Q) %>%
  mutate(
    Q = factor(Q),
    ans = factor(ans, labels = answers)
  ) %>%
  arrange(Q, ans) %>%
  mutate(
    xmin = cumsum(lag(percent, 1, 0)),
    xmax = cumsum(percent), .by = Q
  ) %>%
  mutate(offset = (xmax[3] + xmax[2]) / 2, .by = Q) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("xm"), ~ .x - offset)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Q)) +
  geom_linerange(
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, color = ans),
    ### Adjust linewidth to set width of bars
    linewidth = 20,
    ###
    key_glyph = draw_key_rect
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      (xmin + xmax) / 2,
      label = scales::percent(percent, 1)
    ),
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    labels = variable_names
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(NULL,
    labels = scales::percent,
    breaks = seq(-1, 1, len = 9),
    limits = c(-1, 1)
  ) +
  scale_color_brewer(NULL, palette = "BrBG")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot; but i want a plot more like the one in the 2. edit of my first post! is there a way to just make this plot as barplot(notstacked!)